# Ionic 4 Storage remove

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, async-await, ionic4, ionic-storage

I have a storage for credential token in my Ionic app, and to perform logout action I need to remove the token stored in it. Here goes my LoginService:

```
// imports skipped;

export class LoginService implements CanActivate {
    private authToken: string;
    private httpService: string;

    constructor(
        private handler: HttpBackend,
        private router: Router,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {
        this.httpService = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    private generateToken(login: string, password: string) {
        return btoa(`${login}:${password}`);
    }

    authenticate(login: string, password: string, webserviceURL: string) {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Basic ${this.generateToken(login, password)}`
            })
        };
        return this.httpClient.get(`http://${webserviceURL}/api/version/`, httpOptions);
    }

    async saveToken(login: string, password: string) {
        this.authToken = this.generateToken(login, password);
        return await this.storage.set('AUTH_TOKEN', this.authToken);
    }

    async getToken() {
        return await this.storage.get('AUTH_TOKEN');
    }

    async clearData() {
        this.authToken = null;
        return await this.storage.remove('AUTH_TOKEN');
    }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.authToken) {
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
    }
}
```

and in my test for this service I've got the following:

```
        const expectedToken = btoa('testLogin:testPassword');

        service.saveToken('testLogin', 'testPassword').then(() => {
            service.getToken().then(savedToken => {
                expect(savedToken).toEqual(expectedToken);
            });
        });

        service.clearData().then(() => {
            service.getToken().then(savedToken => {
                expect(savedToken).toBe(null);
            });
        });
```

So any time I run my test, the last test case fails, because for some reason the token is not deleted from the storage. Here's the test output: `Error: Expected 'dGVzdExvZ2luOnRlc3RQYXNzd29yZA==' to be null`. How should I handle removing value from Storage correctly?

Comment: Have you considered that by removing the token, the token will be `undefined` instead?

Comment: the problem is that it is neither `undefined`, nor `null` -- the promise still returns the token that should have been already removed.

Answer (score 0):

2nd attempt... if your code is running in one method then it has to all be nested, or it will just run one after the other?

```
    const expectedToken = btoa('testLogin:testPassword');

    service.saveToken('testLogin', 'testPassword').then(() => {
        service.getToken().then(savedToken => {
            expect(savedToken).toEqual(expectedToken);

            service.clearData().then(() => {
                service.getToken().then(savedToken => {
                    expect(savedToken).toBe(null);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself, but I'd expect something like the following to work:

```
this.storage.set('AUTH_TOKEN', null);
```

or

```
// Actually use a variation of this one myself for one case
this.storage.set('AUTH_TOKEN', '');
```

**Edit:** Both of these are if you need to keep the keys in local storage. Ie- your app expects the key to exist at all times - regardless of state.